# LaTeX to HTML via Pandoc : handle a custom command

Tags: pandoc

I am using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to convert a .tex document to html/epub. In my text I make frequent use of a custom command,
`\subchpbreak` with the following definition:

```
\newcommand{\subchpbreak}{\fancybreak{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\S}}}
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way to have the custom command (i.e. the string `\subchpbreak` be interpreted by the converted or regex replaced by something I can style with css, e.g.

```
<div class='subchpbreak'>&167;</div>
```

I know that I can do string replacement in my tex file, but I would rather not.

Maybe what I should do is write a bash script to do the string replacement and then run Pandoc? Or is there a better way?

---

## A solution from the comments

In the comments, it was suggested that I use `htlatex` instead of pandoc. This does solve the custom command issue nicely. However, I am having an issue with `` and '' being lost.

The culprit seems to be `\usepackage{paratype}`. The below example works as expected without the font package, but ignores the quotes with it.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{ inputenc }
\usepackage{ graphicx }
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{paratype}

\usepackage{xcolor,fix-cm}
\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}

\newcommand{\subchpbreak}{\fancybreak{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\S}}}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{A chapter}
    \lipsum[1]

    ``Alas, this is a quote,'' said the idiot.

    \lipsum[2]    

    \subchpbreak

    \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any response!

Comment: most complete tool for html conversion with support for adding custom commands is  `tex4ht`. if you want to create epub, see [tex4ebook](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook), which is also based on `tex4ht`

Comment: I had an issue with tex4ht ignore double quotes.

E.g.

    ``quotation'' --> quotation

Comment: it might be some problem with your setup, it converts them by default. could you make a `mwe`?

Comment: A shell script would definitely belong on a different site; but for the rest, you've come to the right place.  Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @michal.h21 It seems that the culprit for me  was `\usepackage{paratype}` -- does htlatex not permit font packages? See edited OP for MWE.

Comment: You can use [gpp](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) as an intermediate step in the toolchain.

Comment: @TylerPeckenpaugh htlatex permits font packages, but some of them aren't supported out of the box. I will add details to my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily support custom commands with `tex4ht`. Just move declaration of the commands to standalone package, for example `mycommands.sty`:

```
\newcommand{\subchpbreak}{\fancybreak{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\S}}}
```

and create file with same name, but `.4ht` extension, `mycommands.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{subchpbreak}{1}
\renewcommand\subchpbreak{\a:subchpbreak}
\Configure{subchpbreak}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class='subchpbreak'>&\#167;</div>}}

\Css{.subchpbreak{font-size:1.2em;}}
```

To allow configurability, we need to declare some hooks in which will be inserted html code. These hooks are inserted to redefined commands. In this case, we declared new configuration, `subchpbreak` with one hook, because your command takes no arguments. For commands one parameter, you would need two hooks, to be inserted before and after the parameter, for two parameters you would need three hooks and so on.

The hook is then inserted to redefined command, the hooks are named as `\a:hookname`, `b:hookname`, etc. In our case we use only one hook, so it is just `\a:subchpbreak`.

The hook is configured with

```
\Configure{subchpbreak}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class='subchpbreak'>&\#167;</div>}}
```

we need to use

```
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP
```

because `<p>` elements are inserted in each paragraph, but we don't want them around our `<div>`

You can add stuff to the `.css` file with the `\Css` command.

The resulting html:

```
<!--l. 15--><p class="noindent" >&#8220;Alas, this is a quote,&#8221; said the idiot.
</p>
...
</p>
   <div class='subchpbreak'>§</div>
<!--l. 21--><p class="indent" >
```

[image]

Regarding your problem with fonts, you should use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` for best unicode support. When you use `paratype` fonts, you may see following message in the terminal output:

```
--- warning --- Couldn't find font `PTSerif-Regular-tlf-t1.htf'
```

for each font, `.htf` file must exist. I recently provided a solution for [Droid sans](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247479/2891), in your case you may create following `PTSerif-Regular-tlf-t1.htf` file:

```
.lm-ec
htfcss: PTSerif-Regular-tlf-t1 font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
```

see the linked answer about Droid Sans for details. You may need to create similar files also for italic and bold fonts, if you use them.

Comment: @jon some basic are here: https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht/wiki/tex4ht-tutorial stuff about fonts is unfortunately undocumented